# Grails: how to design/code multiple views with one model

Tags: grails

I'm leading the user through a registration process where it takes multiple view pages to collect the full registration info, which I'm putting into it's own model for now (Registration).  Can you please comment on some key Grails code/design practices in doing this.   Is chain the right way to do this?

Comment: have you looked at spring webflow?

Comment: I don't want to go to level of complexity. I.e. I find taking on things with lots of capability -- no doubt Spring webflow -- also adds a lot of complexity (when it doesn't work as expected).

Comment: spring webflow does add complexity.

Comment: I've done this in the past by storing data in the session. I'm not going to say that's the best practice - its just what I did. You can validate the separate parts with command objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this kind of wizard using [spring webflows](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Plug-ins/web%20flow.html)